# What is the difference between apt-install and in-target apt-get install?

Tags: apt, preseed

The [ubuntu help on preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html) links to [an example file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) which contains this:

> ```
> # This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
> # still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
> # directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
> # packages and run commands in the target system.
> #d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install zsh; in-target chsh -s /bin/zsh
> ```

Is there a difference between using `apt-install zsh` and `in-target apt-get install zsh`?