# When to use pkgsel/include over a preseed/late_command apt-install?

Tags: preseed

The [example file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) for [preseeding bionic](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs04.html) as linked to here contains both

> ````
> # Individual additional packages to install
> #d-i pkgsel/include string openssh-server build-essential ```
> ````

and

> ````
> # This command is run just before the install finishes, but when there is
> # still a usable /target directory. You can chroot to /target and use it
> # directly, or use the apt-install and in-target commands to easily install
> # packages and run commands in the target system.
> #d-i preseed/late_command string apt-install zsh; in-target chsh -s /bin/zsh ```
> ````

How do I decide whether I want to use the `preseed/late_command` version or the `pkgsel/include` version?

My question [What is the difference between apt-install and in-target apt-get install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222602/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-install-and-in-target-apt-get-install) is related but complementary. I expect it to be separate enough of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing the system using a preseed file, one of the steps is to define where are the installation components located (such as main, universe..). This could be a CD, NFS server, FTP or WEB servers, either official or non official. This can be done only once.

When including packages you need to make sure that all of them exist in the selected repository, the repo holds any dependencies (if needed) and are supported by your version. Your automated installation may fail or halt if one of the packages failed to install from any reason.

Any `late_command` is executed when your system installation finished and you have a proper working OS.
This allows you to execute regular commands as if you are connected to the machine. It also does not unmount your installation media if you still need it.

An example for a useful apt-get related late command is to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with other repos, preform `apt update` and then use `apt-get` on packages you did not have while installing the OS.

Comment: Ah, so the only difference is timing when I specify all my repositories (like `mirror/udeb/components multiselect main, restricted, multiverse, universe`)? I guess that means that when one has the choice, it is preferrable to use the `late_command` so that the installation can not fail due to that `apt-get` (?)

Comment: Yes and no. Assuming you are using an official download, or a repository you manage yourself or know for sure what it holds, it is safe to use regular preseed methods. You can always reinstall your OS and fix your preseed if needed. Overall late commands are just a tool that runs post install and works like this: "enter free text here that will act like commands - nothing bad should happen if the command can't be executed". What commands you use and their output is your choice. updating repos is just one of the common uses, as installs tend to get old over time.

Comment: Late commands are by no means a substitute for `base-config apt-setup` and `d-i mirror` stages, as they are critical for your system install since they hold the information about the location of your install components.